# How can I get an instagram users biography and profile data using a query_hash and the graphql endpoint?

Tags: multithreading, graphql, instagram

I am currently getting userprofile information from the following endpoint '/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username=${username}' which works. However it is quickly rate-limited and not suitable for my application.

I would like to use the graphql endpoint for user profile information (biography) so I do not get rate limited.

I cannot figure out how to generate a query_hash for user profile details.

If anyone knows the query_hash for biography information that would be great but even better would be if anyone can explain to me how to generate a query hash for arbitrary data.

I tried md5 hashing a json object which did not generate a valid hash. Also attempted to md5 hash the output of a json object using https://github.com/vkolgi/json-to-graphql-query which also did not produce a valid query_hash according to the instagram graphql endpoint.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.